# Renaming column values based on criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data set consisting of three columns: `time`, `jar` and `measurement_type`

For each unique measurement_type I have one measurement series `jars` `1`, `2`, and `3`, and two measurements the `jar`: `blank`. I want to rename `blank`, so that first measurement in each `measurement_type` is called `blank1` and the second `blank2`

Any ideas?

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("2021-04-02 23:40:20", "2021-04-02 23:41:15", 
"2021-04-02 23:42:10", "2021-04-02 23:43:05", "2021-04-02 23:44:55", 
"2021-04-02 23:45:50", "2021-04-02 23:46:45", "2021-04-02 23:47:40", 
"2021-04-02 23:48:35", "2021-04-02 23:49:30", "2021-04-02 23:50:25", 
"2021-04-02 23:52:15", "2021-04-03 00:36:15", "2021-04-03 00:37:10", 
"2021-04-03 00:39:00", "2021-04-03 00:39:55", "2021-04-03 00:56:25", 
"2021-04-03 00:57:20", "2021-04-03 00:58:15", "2021-04-03 00:59:10", 
"2021-04-03 01:00:05", "2021-04-03 01:01:00", "2021-04-03 01:02:50", 
"2021-04-03 01:03:45", "2021-04-03 01:04:40", "2021-04-03 01:05:35", 
"2021-04-03 01:06:30", "2021-04-03 01:23:54", "2021-04-03 01:24:49", 
"2021-04-03 01:25:44", "2021-04-03 01:26:39", "2021-04-03 01:28:29", 
"2021-04-03 01:29:24", "2021-04-03 01:30:19", "2021-04-03 01:31:14", 
"2021-04-03 01:32:09", "2021-04-03 01:33:04", "2021-04-03 01:33:59", 
"2021-04-03 01:35:49", "2021-04-03 01:36:44", "2021-04-03 01:37:39", 
"2021-04-03 01:38:34", "2021-04-03 01:39:29", "2021-04-03 01:48:39", 
"2021-04-03 01:49:34", "2021-04-03 01:50:29", "2021-04-03 01:58:44", 
"2021-04-03 01:59:39", "2021-04-03 02:00:34", "2021-04-03 02:01:29", 
"2021-04-03 02:11:34", "2021-04-03 02:12:29", "2021-04-03 02:18:54", 
"2021-04-03 02:19:49", "2021-04-03 02:20:44", "2021-04-03 02:21:39", 
"2021-04-03 02:22:34", "2021-04-03 02:23:29", "2021-04-03 02:24:24", 
"2021-04-03 02:25:19", "2021-04-03 02:26:14", "2021-04-03 02:27:09", 
"2021-04-03 02:28:04", "2021-04-03 02:28:59"), jar = c("blank", 
"blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "blank", "blank", "blank", 
"blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", 
"blank", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), measurement_type = c("a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), new_column = c("blank1", 
"blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "blank2", "blank2", 
"blank2", "blank2", "blank2", "blank2", "blank2", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", "blank1", 
"blank1", "blank1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "blank2", "blank2", "blank2", "blank2", 
"blank2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a shorter solution but I would use `data.table::rleid()` function which is really useful for detecting groups of repeated values.
To get the right index corresponding to your example, this value is converted to factor and then to numeric value:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(measurement_type) %>% 
  mutate(
    indx = data.table::rleid(jar),
    indx =  if_else(jar == "blank", 
                    indx, 
                    NA_integer_) %>% 
      as.factor() %>% 
      as.numeric()
  ) %>%  
  mutate(
    new_column = if_else(jar == "blank",
                         paste0(jar, indx),
                         jar)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-indx)
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does?

Comment: If you look at the first part, you will understand how data.table::rleid() works.
```
df %>% 
  group_by(measurement_type) %>% 
  mutate(
    indx = data.table::rleid(jar))
```

The rest is just formating to end up with your output

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` only solution. This should also work

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(measurement_type) %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(jar != lag(jar) & jar=="blank", 1, 0, missing = 1),  
         sequence = cumsum(flag)) %>% 
  mutate(jar = case_when(jar=="blank" ~ paste(jar,sequence, sep = ""),
                         TRUE ~ jar)) %>% 
  select(-new_column, -flag, -sequence)
```

Output:

```
   time                jar    measurement_type
   <chr>               <chr>  <chr>           
 1 2021-04-02 23:40:20 blank1 a               
 2 2021-04-02 23:41:15 blank1 a               
 3 2021-04-02 23:42:10 blank1 a               
 4 2021-04-02 23:43:05 blank1 a               
 5 2021-04-02 23:44:55 blank1 a               
 6 2021-04-02 23:45:50 blank1 a               
 7 2021-04-02 23:46:45 blank1 a               
 8 2021-04-02 23:47:40 1      a               
 9 2021-04-02 23:48:35 1      a               
10 2021-04-02 23:49:30 1      a               
11 2021-04-02 23:50:25 1      a               
12 2021-04-02 23:52:15 1      a               
13 2021-04-03 00:36:15 2      a               
14 2021-04-03 00:37:10 2      a               
15 2021-04-03 00:39:00 2      a               
16 2021-04-03 00:39:55 2      a               
17 2021-04-03 00:56:25 2      a               
18 2021-04-03 00:57:20 blank2 a               
19 2021-04-03 00:58:15 blank2 a               
20 2021-04-03 00:59:10 blank2 a               
21 2021-04-03 01:00:05 blank2 a               
22 2021-04-03 01:01:00 blank2 a               
23 2021-04-03 01:02:50 blank2 a               
24 2021-04-03 01:03:45 blank2 a               
25 2021-04-03 01:04:40 3      a               
26 2021-04-03 01:05:35 3      a               
27 2021-04-03 01:06:30 3      a               
28 2021-04-03 01:23:54 3      a               
29 2021-04-03 01:24:49 3      a               
30 2021-04-03 01:25:44 3      a               
31 2021-04-03 01:26:39 3      a               
32 2021-04-03 01:28:29 blank1 b               
33 2021-04-03 01:29:24 blank1 b               
34 2021-04-03 01:30:19 blank1 b               
35 2021-04-03 01:31:14 blank1 b               
36 2021-04-03 01:32:09 blank1 b               
37 2021-04-03 01:33:04 blank1 b               
38 2021-04-03 01:33:59 blank1 b               
39 2021-04-03 01:35:49 1      b               
40 2021-04-03 01:36:44 1      b               
41 2021-04-03 01:37:39 1      b               
42 2021-04-03 01:38:34 1      b               
43 2021-04-03 01:39:29 1      b               
44 2021-04-03 01:48:39 1      b               
45 2021-04-03 01:49:34 1      b               
46 2021-04-03 01:50:29 1      b               
47 2021-04-03 01:58:44 2      b               
48 2021-04-03 01:59:39 2      b               
49 2021-04-03 02:00:34 2      b               
50 2021-04-03 02:01:29 2      b               
51 2021-04-03 02:11:34 2      b               
52 2021-04-03 02:12:29 2      b               
53 2021-04-03 02:18:54 blank2 b               
54 2021-04-03 02:19:49 blank2 b               
55 2021-04-03 02:20:44 blank2 b               
56 2021-04-03 02:21:39 blank2 b               
57 2021-04-03 02:22:34 blank2 b               
58 2021-04-03 02:23:29 3      b               
59 2021-04-03 02:24:24 3      b               
60 2021-04-03 02:25:19 3      b               
61 2021-04-03 02:26:14 3      b               
62 2021-04-03 02:27:09 3      b               
63 2021-04-03 02:28:04 3      b               
64 2021-04-03 02:28:59 3      b
```